# Clojure say-hi with varargs

Tags: clojure

Input: "Michael" "Julia" "Joe" "Sam"

Output: Hi, Michael, Julia, Joe, and Sam. (pay attention to the commas and the word "and")

Input: nil

Output: Hi, world.

Here is my first attempt:

```
(defn say-hi [& name]
  (print "Hi," name))


user> (say-hi "Michael")
Hi, (Michael)
nil
user> (say-hi "Michael" "Julia")
Hi, (Michael Julia)
nil
```

Question:

1. How to implement default: (no input, say "Hi World!")
2. How to get rid of the parents around names in output?
3. How to implement the commas separation and add the conjunction word "and"?

Comment: Perhaps return the output instead of printing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, Clojure supports multi-arity functions, so you could do something like this to achieve default behaviour:

```
(defn say-hi
  ([] (say-hi "World"))
  ([& names] ...))
```

Then, what you want is to take a seq and join all the strings it contains together, using `", "` in between. The `clojure.string` namespaces contains lots of string manipulation functions, one of them being `clojure.string/join`:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as string])
(string/join ", " ["Michael", "Julia"])
;; => "Michael, Julia"
```

But the last element of the seq should be concatenated using `" and "` as a separator, so you'll end up with something like this:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as string])
(defn say-hi
  ([] (say-hi "World"))
  ([& names]
   (if (next names)
     (format "Hi, %s, and %s!"
             (string/join ", " (butlast names))
             (last names))
     (format "Hi, %s!" (first names)))))
```

Note that you have to differentiate between the single- and multi-name cases and `(next names)` basically checks whether the seq contains more than one element. (You could achieve the same by adding another arity to the function.)

```
(say-hi)
;; => "Hi, World!"

(say-hi "Michael")
;; => "Hi, Michael!"

(say-hi "Michael" "Julia" "Joe" "Sam")
;; => "Hi, Michael, Julia, Joe, and Sam!"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation -- it's quite clear and easy to understand. The multi-arity function make the code easy to read. and `(if (next name) ...)` check works very well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clojure.string/join`:

```
(use '[clojure.string :only [join]])

(defn sentencify [& elems]
  (->>
    [(join ", " (butlast elems)) (last elems)]
    (remove empty?)
    (join " and ")))

(defn say-hi [& name]
  (print "Hi," (if name
                  (sentencify name)
                  "World!")))
```

Comment: I'm afraid the sentencify part doesn't work: `(say-hi "Michael")
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.core$name  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
`

Comment: Fixed typo. `sentencify` should accept varargs also.

Answer (score 0):

A concise solution:

```
(defn say-hi [& names]
  (let [names (case (count names)
                0 ["world"]
                1 names
                (concat (butlast names) (list (str "and " (last names)))))]
    (->> names, (cons "Hi"), (interpose ", "), (apply str))))

(say-hi)
;"Hi, world"

(say-hi "Michael")
;"Hi, Michael"

(say-hi "Michael" "Julia" "Joe" "Sam")
;"Hi, Michael, Julia, Joe, and Sam"
```

For long lists of `names`, you would want to eschew `count`, `last`, and `butlast`, maybe by pouring `names` into a vector first.

---

To print (as the question does) rather than return the formatted string, append `print` to the final form:

```
(->> names, (cons "Hi"), (interpose ", "), (apply str), print)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works and the concept even works for larger problems. By the way, how do you configure the REPL output starts with semicolon? It is really convenient to copy and past. (I'm using Emacs+Cider-nrepl.)

Comment: @Nick I faked the output layout. I did it in a LightTable instarepl.